# Update the text entry widget in a django_jsonform JSONField

Tags: django, django-forms, widget

I'm using a `JSONField` from `django_jsonform` for a json column in my DB.  On the admin page Django renders a nice form that allows users to add entries to the json according to the schema.

I want to switch out the text entry input field (a Textinput, I think) for string inputs in the JSONField form with a rich text entry widget. I've tried overwriting the JSONField widget with a rich text widget (I'm using TinyMCE) but that replaces the whole thing and just prints the dumped json string in it.

Is it possible to override internal widgets of the JSONField form?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it's not possible to override the internal widgets provided by django-jsonform.

However, I do have plans to include a richtext input widget. But that won't be anytime soon and it would be a pretty basic one (not as extensive as TinyMCE).

I've just created [issue #120](https://github.com/bhch/django-jsonform/issues/120) on Github to track this (so maybe subscribe to that issue as well).

---

Meanwhile, if you trust your users, you can let them add raw HTML and display the text in your templates using the `safe` filter. You can also sanitize the input data using something line [django-bleach](https://django-bleach.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to remove unwanted tags and only keep allowed tags.